# I want to make a discord blacklister bot that reads messages but i can't make him read the messages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, discord, blacklist, discord.net

I want to make a discord bot to blacklist certain words and for that i was trying to first read a message that was sent by a user and check if a word in that message is blacklisted and then remove the message but i don't know how to make the bot read the messages

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [**Where to Start**](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), then address your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read messages you need to assign a callback function to the MessageRecieved event that Discord.net provides you with.

```
public class Program {

    public static DiscordClient client;

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        // Create a discord client
        client = new DiscordClient(x => {

                x.AppName = "Your App Name";

                x.AppUrl = "";

                x.MessageCacheSize = 0;

                x.UsePermissionsCache = true;

                x.EnablePreUpdateEvents = true;

                x.LogLevel = LogSeverity.Debug;

                x.LogHandler = OnLogMessage;

                });

        // Assign a callback to the MessageRecieved event on client
        client.MessageReceived += OnMessageRecieved;

    }

    // Our MessageRecieved callback
    public static void OnMessageRecieved(object sender, MessageEventArgs args) {
        // Your code to handle messages here, the message string can be accessed by args.Message.Text
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you that kinda helped but i can't figure out the how to check if the message is blacklisted and delete it if it is.I get that i have to write what i want to do with the message in those brackets but i can't use the same lines as in telling it what to do in a command written by a person so if you could help me out one more time i'd be super grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i did something and now i have this

```
 public static async void OnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Message.Text.Contains(toBlacklist.ToString()))
        {
            Message[] blacklistedMessagesToDelete;
            blacklistedMessagesToDelete = await e.Channel.DownloadMessages(1);

            await e.Channel.DeleteMessages(blacklistedMessagesToDelete);
        }
    }
```

but the toBlacklist is an array with more words in it and if i don't pass in a string in quotation marks instead of it, it won't delete the message

Answer (score 0):

Some very easy and sloppy code but it should work

```
public static async void OnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
{
    bool found = false; //temporary bool, most likely unneeded
    foreach (var word in toBlacklist)
    {
        if (e.Message.RawText.ToLower().Contains(word.ToLower()))
        {
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (found)
    {
        await e.Message.Delete();
    }
}
```